# Is there a way to select Safari's search (Google) bar (top right) with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, safari

I'm talking about the field accessible with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I search Google **a lot**.

On Windows and Linux this is usually accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu for this is hidden under Edit > Find > Google Search…. The shortcut is <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Sidenote: This works in Google Chrome and Firefox as well.

Comment: Personally, I find the ⌘L ⇥ no hardship to type at all. Using two modifiers at once requires more contortions of the fingers, while the tab key lies comfortably close to my left little finger. Plus, it's one less key combination to remember. (But my brain is getting old. YMMV.)

Comment: Safari has started to get slightly choppy while scrolling. Rather than start deleting cache files and whatnot in an attempt to fix that, I'm going to see if Firefox and Chrome offer a better browsing experience. The upshot is Command+K works for going to google search on Firefox! On Chrome, the omnibar works as search.